# Non-dissipative system attractors

Tags: hamiltonian

I am currently learning about dynamical systems. I understand that dissipative systems have attractors but can not find anything online about whether or not non-dissipative systems have attractors. It may be that my understanding of attractors is not complete but any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, so this is at best a partial answer.

*Non-linearity*, rather than *dissipation*, is the key feature to have attractors.

For example, non-linear dynamical systems with dimension $d\ge2$ may show
[Hopf bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation) and then
a [limit cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) which, if stable, is an example of an attractor.